# cardView not looking properly, the cards are constricted

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[This is the problem , when i'm runing it on the phone it's looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Rhh.jpg)

This is the code i used for the cards for every " row" , i tried few ways none of them worked. everytime when running it on the phone it just constricted. There is another way to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

That's the code for the recyclerView main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="397dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The code for CustomViewHolder

```
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_view,parent,false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view) ;
}
```

Comment: Can you give screen shuts ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Rhh.jpg , that's on the phone @F.sh

Comment: Post your code for `onCreateViewHolder()`, please

Comment: Did you try to replace the ConstraintLayout with RelativeLayout ?

Comment: @BenP. i added the code

Comment: @F.sh Yes it just did a mess in the layout and won't let me move the TextViews as i want

Comment: I was hoping you were inflating the layout incorrectly, but you're not... hmm...

Comment: why android:layout_width="0dp" is 0, try to give some value like 200dp for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've isolated the problem: your `RecyclerView` is inside a `ConstraintLayout`, and your `RecyclerView`'s width is defined by constraining its left and right sides to the parent. For some reason (I'm not sure why), this causes the adapter to be unable to determine how wide the parent is when it creates the first batch of views, so the item views are functionally `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for the width.

You can work around this by hosting your `RecyclerView` in some viewgroup other than `ConstraintLayout`. If that's not an option for you, I'm not sure how else to proceed.

Comment: Great it worked! i put the recyclerView in different layout and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're quite welcome. If this solved your problem, consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer, as this will indicate to future visitors that the answer was helpful (comments can be deleted at any time).

Comment: Done! just one question, when using Relative layout it's really hard to put every TextView where i want. I move one 4 others move too. there's an easier way?

Comment: @AdirBenAmi what is your desired final output? Right now, everything is just in a row, so I'd recommend a horizontal LinearLayout, but if you're looking for something more complex I'd need to know what.

Comment: I have few Text views that i use as titles , they're on top of the cardView and all the TextViews in the same line, it's really hard to place everything the way is want, Do you think horizontal LinearLayout is the way to work with it?